# Is using PLpgSQL function to find a value in a table a bad design?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

For a clearer structure code i created a function in PLpgSQL that perform a lookup in a table
The function is then launch per row ( select myfunc(_id, _sometable) as my_return_val from ... )

I could of course perform the same task with a 'classic' left join on the whole Query/table .

I red here and there that SQL is a declarative language only and that it's te planifier that choose the better way to perform a task (using cost etc...)

I then Wonder if using a function is a very bad design that would kill the performance or if the planificator can deal with it and understand that i will perform the same lookup for each row and then interpret it as a classical join operation ?

PL seems to be very powerfull but i'm affraid it also comes with great -not yet understood- responsabilities...

Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: no it isn't bad design you are supplement the internal function with your user defined, so if your query is efficient and fast perfect

Comment: If calling the function results in running per query per row from the outer query, then this is a bad idea and will not scale.

Comment: yes, @a_horse_with_no_name has true. It can depends, but usually wrapping SQL function is not good, and can have terrible impact on performance. There can be some exceptions why it is necessary like security reasons, but it should be an exception. The problem is in optimization. Function can be optimization fence - and instead optimization of one query, optimizer does optimization two independent queries - and it can disallow to find optimal plan.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. I use the fonction in a trigger that fire 'per row'. Should i rather fire the trigger 'per statement' and do an update of the whole target table using a classical join operation ? Is an insert into on an 'after insert / per row' trigger also a Bad design ?

Comment: Another option would define your function as [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createfunction.html) instead of a plpgsql function. That seems to remove most of the overhead of the function call. `create function(<parmaters>) returns <return> language SQL as $$ select ... ; $$;`

Comment: @Cesco2142 - it depends on an context. Insert in trigger is expensive operation, but sometimes it is necessary (logging, auditing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the called bad performance in pgplsql vs sql but pgplsql also have immense amount of utilities that makes the cost difference not only affordable but justified.
If performance is the problem then you can try to use C Language functions that by default postgres gives a 1 cost to them instead of the default 100 for plpgsql,plpython and any other languages.
in the example below the EXPLAIN shows the cost of the function for the CPU and it is based on the sum of the objects in use :
The formula postgresql uses for calculate the explain cost plus some examples of explain below,is necessary to sum everything from the table (indexes , foreign keys ,sequence): references : https://postgrespro.com/blog/pgsql/5969403

```
SELECT relname , relpages*current_setting('seq_page_cost')::numeric + 
reltuples*current_setting('cpu_tuple_cost')::numeric as cost
FROM pg_class
--WHERE relname='tablename';

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a() RETURNS SET OF INTEGER AS $$
 SELECT 1;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM a() CROSS JOIN (Values(1),(2),(3)) as foo;

Nested Loop (cost=0.25..47.80 rows=3000 width=8)
 -> Function Scan on a (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=4)
 -> Materialize (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=3 width=4)
 -> Values Scan on "*VALUES*" (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4)
(4 rows)
```

If two functions with COST 0.0001 AND 10000 get executed on the same time as the predicate of a SELECT statement the query planner will execute first the function of cost 0.0001 and only later the 10000 cost condition as you can see in this example below.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM pg_language WHERE lanname ILIKE '%sql%' AND slow_
function(lanname)AND fast_function(lanname);
 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on pg_language (cost=0.00..101.05 rows=1 width=114)
 Filter: (fast_function(lanname) AND (lanname ~~* '%sql%'::text) AND 
slow_function(lanname))
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I do not have a performance concern in that case do i'll stick with plpgsql fonction, but i note that it's a bad design and will stick to pure SQL fonction whenever it's possible. I'll also have a look to C fonction but i think that for basic join i can keep SQL

Comment: In this case, the cost is not too important  (cost of function call is just too synthetic number). More important is time - use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: added the https://postgrespro.com/blog/pgsql/5969403 link with cost formulas of postgresql ,the cost does not change from a hardware to another since it is estimated from the objects in use